# Better error message for stopifnot?

Tags: r

I am using `stopifnot` and I understand it just returns the first value that was not `TRUE`. I f that is some freaky dynamic expression someone who is not into the custom function cannot really make something out of that. So I would love to add a custom error message. Any suggestions?

```
Error: length(unique(nchar(check))) == 1 is not TRUE
```

Basically states that the elements of the vector `check` do not have the same length.
Is there a way of saying: `Error: Elements of your input vector do not have the same length!`?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use `stop` and an `if` statement:

```
if(length(unique(nchar(check))) != 1) 
  stop("Error: Elements of your input vector do not have the same length!")
```

Just remember that `stopifnot` has the convenience of stating the negative, so your condition in the `if` needs to be the negation of your stop condition.

---

This is what the error message looks like:

```
> check = c("x", "xx", "xxx")
> if(length(unique(nchar(check))) != 1) 
+   stop("Error: Elements of your input vector do not have the same length!")

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  Error: Elements of your input vector do not have the same length!
```

Comment: what's stop if not good for then? I mean using if is the intuitive solution. It's there in almost every language, even in english. Is there some particular use case for stopifnot?

Comment: @ran2 it's a lot quicker to write `stopifnot`.

Comment: @ran2 The use case for `stopifnot` is precisely what you are using it for at the moment.  It's very intuitive.  But it doesn't produce pretty error messages.  Horses for courses, as they say in English.

Comment: @ran2. `stopifnot` is a quick way to check multiple conditions on the input. so for instance, if you could say `stopifnot(A > 0, B < = 0, C == TRUE)` and ensure that the code stops when either of the three conditions are not satisfied.

Answer (score 38):

A custom message can be added as a label to your expression:

```
stopifnot("Elements of your input vector do not have the same length!" =
  length(unique(nchar(check))) == 1)

# Error: Elements of your input vector do not have the same length!
```

Comment: this is a great answer, simple, base-R and not obvious. You just saved me having to load assert_that in a lot of everyday use cases!

Comment: This looks like an awesome solution but seems to be R version dependent. It's not working for me on 3.5.3. What version were you using?

Comment: Nevermind, I see it was added as functionality in R 4.0.0.

Answer (score 17):

The `assertive` and `assertthat` packages have more readable check functions.

```
library(assertthat)
assert_that(length(unique(nchar(check))) == 1)
## Error: length(unique(nchar(check))) == 1 are not all true.

library(assertive)
assert_is_scalar(unique(nchar(check)))
## Error: unique(nchar(check)) does not have length one.

if(!is_scalar(unique(nchar(check)))) 
{
  stop("Elements of check have different numbers of characters.")
}
## Error: Elements of check have different numbers of characters.
```

Comment: nice package. Do you think it is possible to implement a custom message directly in the assertions. eg :`is_scalar(..., msg="")`?

Comment: @DJJ I toyed with this idea for while, but decided against it. https://bitbucket.org/richierocks/assertive/issues/16/allow-overriding-error-messages  If you have a strong opinion on the matter, comment on the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Your concerns are founded but sometimes the cause of the error can be quite difficult to pinpoint. I have found my way around it with the following: `try(assert_is_scalar(...),stop(mymsg))`.

Answer (score 8):

What about embedding the `stopifnot` into `tryCatch` and then recasting the exception with `stop` using customized message?

Something like:

```
tryCatch(stopifnot(...,error=stop("Your customized error message"))
```

Unlike some other solutions this does not require additional packages. Compared to using `if` statement combined with `stop` you retain the performance advantages of `stopifnot`, when you use new R versions. Since R version 3.5.0 `stopifnot` evaluates expressions sequentially and stops on first failure.

Comment: The reference to version 3.5.0 comes from here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/stopifnot.html

Comment: It should be: tryCatch(stopifnot(...), error=function() stop(msg))

Answer (score 7):

Or you could package it up.

```
assert <- function (expr, error) {
  if (! expr) stop(error, call. = FALSE)
}
```

So you have:

```
> check = c("x", "xx", "xxx")
> assert(length(unique(nchar(check))) == 1, "Elements of your input vector do not have the same length!")

Error: Elements of your input vector do not have the same length!
```

Comment: Here is a version that provides a default error message that mimics stopifnot()'s message.                                                                                                               <br/>```assert <- function (expr, msg) {
  if(missing(msg)) msg <- paste("Condition",deparse(as.list(match.call())$expr), "is not TRUE")
  if (! expr) stop(msg, call. = FALSE)
}``` So, assert(is.character(2)) returns `Error: Condition is.character(dir) is not TRUE`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```r
same_length <- FALSE
stopifnot("Elements of your input vector do not have the same length!" = same_length)
#> Error : Elements of your input vector do not have the same length!
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you check out Hadley's `testthat` package. It allows for intuitive testing: the names of the functions are great and the way you write them is like a sentence -- "I expect that `length(unique(nchar(check)))` is [exactly|approximately] 1". The errors produced are informative.

See here:
http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Wickham.pdf

In your case,

```
> library(testthat)
> check = c("x", "xx", "xxx")
> expect_that(length(unique(nchar(check))), equals(1))
Error: length(unique(nchar(check))) not equal to 1
Mean relative difference: 2
```

Also note that you don't have the problem that @Andrie referenced with sometimes having to think about double negatives with `stopifnot`. I know it seems simple, but it caused me many headaches!

Comment: I agree with using `testthat` for testing - I use this all the time.  However, I find the messages produced by `testthat` very confusing.  This is perfectly acceptable for a developer, but not necessarily the way forward for producing error messages in a package.

Comment: @Andrie Good point! You mean because in `testthat` you don't specify the error message yourself?

Comment: +1, thx for pointing me to testthat – it makes the thread more comprehensive. Probably going to accept Andrie's answer because I was exactly looking for a way to specify error messages that users understand.

Comment: `testthat` is for development-time testing; `assertive` and `assertthat` are for run-time testing. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answers already provided are quite good, and mine is just an addition to that collection. For some people it could be more convenient to use one-liner in form of the following function:

```
stopifnotinform <- function(..., message = "err") {
  args <- list(...)
  if (length(args) == 0) {
    return(NULL)
  }
  for (i in 1:length(args)) {
    result <- args[[i]]
    if (is.atomic(result) && result == FALSE) {
      stop(message)
    }
  }
}

# throws an error
stopifnotinform(is.integer(1L), is.integer(2), message = "Some number(s) provided is not an integer")
# continues with execution
stopifnotinform(is.integer(1L), is.integer(2L), message = "Some number(s) provided is not an integer")
```

Bear in mind that this solution provides you with only one (common) error message for all parameters in `...`.

Comment: such a shame this is not a default!