# Include error messages from testthat in R markdown document

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, testthat

I want to include error messages in an R markdown pdf report. This works well:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

This will be knitted and show the error message in the pdf.
```{r, error = TRUE}
stopifnot(2 == 3)
```
````

However, if I try the same approach with an error that comes from `testthat`, my document does not knit anymore.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

This will not knit
```{r, error = TRUE}
library(testthat)
expect_equal(2, 3)
```
````

Why is that? And what can I do to include error messages from `testthat`'s `expect_something` functions without wrapping them up in a test?

I think this must be possible since Hadley Wickham includes many error messages in his book R packages that come directly from `expect_something`-functions.

This is related, but not answered in [Include errors in R markdown package vignette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187085/include-errors-in-r-markdown-package-vignette) and [How to skip error checking at Rmarkdown compiling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280043/how-to-skip-error-checking-at-rmarkdown-compiling)

Comment: testthat is not supported in knitr. See https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1413

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a test:

````
```{r, error = TRUE}
library(testthat)
test_that("Test A", {
  expect_equal(2, 3)
})
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This might be a workaround. But I still hope to be able to include errors from `expect_something` functions directly. See my edit of the question.

Comment: As far as I can see, all error messages come from comparisons contained in tests. If there are chunks with comparisons only, he has set `eval = F` (https://github.com/hadley/r-pkgs/blob/master/tests.rmd)

Comment: That's true. But he only recently changed that. https://github.com/hadley/r-pkgs/commit/649b73691b469dae68db63b9cd77e18e527dd808 So there might be a problem with that and including error messages from `expect_something` functions might not be possible at the moment..

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the reason for the behavior (good question!), but this could be a workaround:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

This will knit
```{r, error = TRUE}
library(testthat)
# expect_equal(2, 3)
# skip_if_not(2, 3)
assertthat::assert_that(2 == 3)
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly this does not really help since I want to include the more informative error messages from the `testthat` package.
Notice that `expect_equal(2, 3)` and `skip_if_not(2, 3)` will not throw the same error messages.

Comment: Perhaps `assertthat` is better? From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8343509/5784831). See edit...